# How to erase ReactJs folder?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

OS -- Ubuntu 18.04
Node -- 10.16.3
NPM -- 6.9.0
What did I do? -- npx create-react-app my-app

I'm trying to erase "my-app" folder

using vscode, such as nautilus, it asks me to delete permanenty. It doesnt work.

using bash I get these erros:

```
sudo rmdir my-app/
rmdir: falhou em remover 'my-app/': Diretório não vazio // not empty

sudo rmdir -f my-app/
rmdir: opção inválida -- “f”
```

*rf doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

`man rmdir` says:

```
NAME
       rmdir - remove empty directories

SYNOPSIS
       rmdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...

DESCRIPTION
       Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), if they are empty.
```

Your directory is not empty. Use `rm -r` instead:

```
rm -r my-app
```

*Side note:* Treat `sudo` like a heavy hammer. You don't want to use it every time something doesn't work immediately. Fragile stuff doesn't like being hit with heavy hammers. Some stuff may seem to work initially, but later you'll learn that you broke something by using `sudo` irresponsibly. Many problems can be solved by deep diving and understanding them, not just by force.